# Get column name where value is something in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

I'm trying to find, at each timestamp, the column name in a dataframe for which the value matches with the one in a timeseries  at the same timestamp.

Here is my dataframe:

```
>>> df
                            col5        col4        col3        col2        col1
1979-01-01 00:00:00  1181.220328  912.154923  648.848635  390.986156  138.185861
1979-01-01 06:00:00  1190.724461  920.767974  657.099560  399.395338  147.761352
1979-01-01 12:00:00  1193.414510  918.121482  648.558837  384.632475  126.254342
1979-01-01 18:00:00  1171.670276  897.585930  629.201469  366.652033  109.545607
1979-01-02 00:00:00  1168.892579  900.375126  638.377583  382.584568  132.998706

>>> df.to_dict()
{'col4': {<Timestamp: 1979-01-01 06:00:00>: 920.76797370744271, <Timestamp: 1979-01-01 00:00:00>: 912.15492332839756, <Timestamp: 1979-01-01 18:00:00>: 897.58592995700656, <Timestamp: 1979-01-01 12:00:00>: 918.1214819496729}, 'col5': {<Timestamp: 1979-01-01 06:00:00>: 1190.7244605667831, <Timestamp: 1979-01-01 00:00:00>: 1181.2203275146587, <Timestamp: 1979-01-01 18:00:00>: 1171.6702763228691, <Timestamp: 1979-01-01 12:00:00>: 1193.4145103184442}, 'col2': {<Timestamp: 1979-01-01 06:00:00>: 399.39533771666561, <Timestamp: 1979-01-01 00:00:00>: 390.98615646597591, <Timestamp: 1979-01-01 18:00:00>: 366.65203285812231, <Timestamp: 1979-01-01 12:00:00>: 384.63247469269874}, 'col3': {<Timestamp: 1979-01-01 06:00:00>: 657.09956023625466, <Timestamp: 1979-01-01 00:00:00>: 648.84863460462293, <Timestamp: 1979-01-01 18:00:00>: 629.20146872682449, <Timestamp: 1979-01-01 12:00:00>: 648.55883747413225}, 'col1': {<Timestamp: 1979-01-01 06:00:00>: 147.7613518219286, <Timestamp: 1979-01-01 00:00:00>: 138.18586102094068, <Timestamp: 1979-01-01 18:00:00>: 109.54560722575859, <Timestamp: 1979-01-01 12:00:00>: 126.25434189361377}}
```

And the time series with values I want to match at each timestamp:

```
>>> ts
1979-01-01 00:00:00    1181.220328
1979-01-01 06:00:00    657.099560
1979-01-01 12:00:00    126.254342
1979-01-01 18:00:00    109.545607
Freq: 6H

>>> ts.to_dict()
{<Timestamp: 1979-01-01 06:00:00>: 657.09956023625466, <Timestamp: 1979-01-01 00:00:00>: 1181.2203275146587, <Timestamp: 1979-01-01 18:00:00>: 109.54560722575859, <Timestamp: 1979-01-01 12:00:00>: 126.25434189361377}
```

Then the result would be:

```
>>> df_result
                             value  Column
1979-01-01 00:00:00    1181.220328  col5
1979-01-01 06:00:00    657.099560   col3
1979-01-01 12:00:00    126.254342   col1
1979-01-01 18:00:00    109.545607   col1
```

I hope my question is clear enough. Anyone has an idea how to get df_result?

Thanks

Greg

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is one, perhaps inelegant, way to do it:

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame(ts, columns=['value'])
```

Set up a function which grabs the column name which contains the value (from `ts`):

```
def get_col_name(row):    
    b = (df.ix[row.name] == row['value'])
    return b.index[b.argmax()]
```

*for each row, test which elements equal the value, and extract column name of a True.*

And [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) it (row-wise):

```
In [3]: df_result.apply(get_col_name, axis=1)
Out[3]: 
1979-01-01 00:00:00    col5
1979-01-01 06:00:00    col3
1979-01-01 12:00:00    col1
1979-01-01 18:00:00    col1
```

i.e. use  `df_result['Column'] = df_result.apply(get_col_name, axis=1)`.

.

Note: there is quite a lot going on in `get_col_name` so perhaps it warrants some further explanation:

```
In [4]: row = df_result.irow(0) # an example row to pass to get_col_name

In [5]: row
Out[5]: 
value    1181.220328
Name: 1979-01-01 00:00:00

In [6]: row.name # use to get rows of df
Out[6]: <Timestamp: 1979-01-01 00:00:00>

In [7]: df.ix[row.name]
Out[7]: 
col5    1181.220328
col4     912.154923
col3     648.848635
col2     390.986156
col1     138.185861
Name: 1979-01-01 00:00:00

In [8]: b = (df.ix[row.name] == row['value'])
        #checks whether each elements equal row['value'] = 1181.220328  

In [9]: b
Out[9]: 
col5     True
col4    False
col3    False
col2    False
col1    False
Name: 1979-01-01 00:00:00

In [10]: b.argmax() # index of a True value
Out[10]: 0

In [11]: b.index[b.argmax()] # the index value (column name)
Out[11]: 'col5'
```

*It might be there is more efficient way to do this...*

Answer (score 44):

Just wanted to add that for a situation where *multiple* columns may have the value and you want *all* the column names in a list, you can do the following (e.g. get all column names with a value = 'x'):

```
df.apply(lambda row: row[row == 'x'].index, axis=1)
```

The idea is that you turn each row into a series (by adding `axis=1`) where the column names are now turned into the index of the series. You then filter your series with a condition (e.g. `row == 'x'`), then take the index values (aka column names!).

Comment: Great answer; particularly useful for one-hot encoded columns.

Comment: To get the list df.apply(lambda row: row[row == 1].index.tolist() , axis=1)

Answer (score 15):

Following on from Andy's detailed answer, the solution to selecting the column name of the highest value per row can be simplified to a single line:

```
df['column'] = df.apply(lambda x: df.columns[x.argmax()], axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 12):

### Use [`df.eq()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) for ~300x speedup over `df.apply()`

The other answers are fine but very slow compared to the vectorized [`df.eq()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html):

```py
df.loc[ts.index].eq(ts, axis=0).idxmax(axis=1)

# 1979-01-01 00:00:00    col5
# 1979-01-01 06:00:00    col3
# 1979-01-01 12:00:00    col1
# 1979-01-01 18:00:00    col1
# dtype: object
```

- [`loc[ts.index]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) returns `df` rows that match `ts` timestamps
- [`eq(ts, axis=0)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) compares each `ts` value to one row (`axis=0`) of `df`

  - `eq(ts[:, None])` would be the [numpy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/theory.broadcasting.html#array-broadcasting-in-numpy) equivalent
- [`idxmax(axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) returns the first matching column (`axis=1`) in each row

[image: vectorized vs df.apply timings]

<sup>*Testing data:*</sup>
<sup>*`index = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=n, freq='1T')`*</sup>
<sup>*`df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(n, 5)), index=index).add_prefix('col')`*</sup>
<sup>*`ts = df.apply(np.random.choice, axis=1).sample(frac=0.9)`*</sup>

---

### Use [`np.isclose()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) for safer float comparison

Unless you have a specific reason to test strict equality, [floats should be compared with a tolerance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5595425/13138364), e.g., using [`isclose()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html):

- Use [`isclose()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) to compare `df` with `ts`, where `[:, None]` [stretches `ts` to the same size as `df`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/theory.broadcasting.html#array-broadcasting-in-numpy):

  ```py
  close = np.isclose(df.loc[ts.index], ts[:, None])

  # array([[ True, False, False, False, False],
  #        [False, False,  True, False, False],
  #        [False, False, False, False,  True],
  #        [False, False, False, False,  True]])
  ```
- Then, as before, use [`idxmax(axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) to extract the first matching column per row:

  ```py
  pd.DataFrame(close, index=ts.index, columns=df.columns).idxmax(axis=1)

  # 1979-01-01 00:00:00    col5
  # 1979-01-01 06:00:00    col3
  # 1979-01-01 12:00:00    col1
  # 1979-01-01 18:00:00    col1
  # dtype: object
  ```

Using [`isclose()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) will be just as fast as [`eq()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) (and thus *much* faster than `df.apply()`:

[image: vectorized eq vs isclose timings]

---

<sub>*Note that if you have more complex joining conditions, use [`df.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), [`df.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), or [`df.reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html). For OP's question, these are overkill but would look something like this:*</sub>

- `df.merge(ts.rename('ts'), left_index=True, right_index=True)`
- `df.join(ts.rename('ts'), how='right')`
- `df.reindex(ts.index)`

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to create a new column to indicate which existing column has the biggest value for a row. This gave me the desired string column label:

```
df['column_with_biggest_value'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)
```