# Get columns names if 'value' is in a list pandas Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, identity-column

I need to find columns names if they contain one of these words `COMPLETE`, `UPDATED` and `PARTIAL`

This is my code, not working.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['', 'COMPLETE',''], 
             'col2': ['UPDATED', '',''],
             'col3': ['','PARTIAL','']},
            )
print(df)
items=["COMPLETE", "UPDATED", "PARTIAL"]
if x in items:
    print (df.columns)
```

this is the desired output:

[image]

I tried to get inspired by this question [Get column name where value is something in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734695/get-column-name-where-value-is-something-in-pandas-dataframe) but I couldn't wrap my head around it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do `isin` and `stack` and `where`:

```
s=df.where(df.isin(items)).stack().reset_index(level=0,drop=True).sort_index()
s
col1    COMPLETE
col2     UPDATED
col3     PARTIAL
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it.

```
# check each column for any matches from the items list.
matched = df.isin(items).any(axis=0)

# produce a list of column labels with a match.
matches = list(df.columns[matched])
```