# Pandas Find name of column in which a string is found

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following dataframe

```
data = [['Alex','Dog'],['Bob','Cat'],['Clarke','Giraffe']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'])


+--------+---------+
|  Name  | Animal  |
+--------+---------+
| Alex   | Dog     |
| Bob    | Cat     |
| Clarke | Giraffe |
+--------+---------+
```

What is the most efficient way of getting the name of the column where the string `Giraffe` is found (i.e. Animal). We can assume there is only one of those string in the entire DataFrame.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734695/get-column-name-where-value-is-something-in-pandas-dataframe I hope this will help you

Comment: Try `df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('Giraffe')).any()`

Comment: ``df.columns[df.eq("Giraffe").any().array]``

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find column whose name contains a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285380/find-column-whose-name-contains-a-specific-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely not the best/elegant answer but it does the trick

```
word = 'Giraffe'
df.columns[df[df==word].notna().sum()>0][0]
```

returns 'Animal' as a string.

This does only work if we assume there is only one column which can contain the word.