# pandas dataframe - how to find multiple column names with minimum values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (small sample shown below, it has more columns), and I want to find the column names with the minimum values.

[image]

Right now, I have the following code to deal with it:

```
finaldf['min_pillar_score'] = finaldf.iloc[:, 2:9].idxmin(axis="columns")
```

This works fine, but does not return multiple values of column names in case there is more than one instance of minimum values. How can I change this to return multiple column names in case there is more than one instance of the minimum value?

Please note, I want row wise results, i.e. minimum column names for each row.

Thanks!

Comment: please do not post images of data, provide the data as **text**

Comment: I cant preserve the formatting as text

Comment: wrap the data in triple backticks, I'll edit your post if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the code below and see if it's in the output format you'd anticipated. it produces the intended result at least.

result will be stored in `mins`.

```
mins = df.idxmin(axis="columns")

for i, r in df.iterrows():
    mins[i] = list(r[r == r[mins[i]]].index)
```

[Get column name where value is something in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734695/get-column-name-where-value-is-something-in-pandas-dataframe) might be helpful also.

*EDIT: adding an image of the output and the full code context.*[image]

Comment: thanks so much! this was so helpful, you're a legend!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this input as `df`:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  5  8  9  5
1  0  0  1  7
2  6  9  2  4
3  5  2  4  2
4  4  7  7  9
```

You can use the underlying numpy array to get the min value, then compare the values to the min and get the columns that have a match:

```
s = df.eq(df.to_numpy().min()).any()
list(s[s].index)
```

output: `['A', 'B']`

Comment: Hi, I wanted row wise results, i.e. minimum column names per row.

Comment: I have edited the question to include this

Comment: @Ray92 please update your question with the data as text, and please provide the expected output for clarity