# Pandas: how to index dataframe for certain value or string without knowing the column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Although it seems very detrimental, I am having a hard time getting the index of a dataframe for a certain string or value at a random position in the dataframe.

I made an example dataframe:

```
fruits = {
    'column1':["Apples","Pears","Bananas","Oranges","Strawberries"],
    'column2':[1,2,3,4,5],
    'column3':["Kiwis","Mangos","Pineapples","Grapes","Melons"]
          }

df = pd.DataFrame(fruits)

        column1  column2     column3
0        Apples        1       Kiwis
1         Pears        2      Mangos
2       Bananas        3  Pineapples
3       Oranges        4      Grapes
4  Strawberries        5      Melons
```

Now I want to get the position index of Mangos, without having the knowledge in which column or row it exists. So far I succeeded in getting the row index:

```
print(df.loc[df.isin(["Mangos"]).any(axis=1)].index)
```

Which results in:

```
Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')
```

But now I would also like to retrieve the column index or column name.

This thread is a very simplified version of [Get column name where value is something in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734695/get-column-name-where-value-is-something-in-pandas-dataframe), but I could not figure out the code using the other thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
df.columns[df.isin(['Mangos']).any()])
```

```
Index(['column3'], dtype='object')
```

Or to just get the column name:

```
df.columns[df.isin(['Mangos']).any()][0]
# column3
```

To get the index of the column, try:

```
df.columns.get_indexer(df.columns[df.isin(['Mangos']).any()])
# [2]
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) the dataframe to reshape into multiindex series, then use boolean indexing to get the index

```
s = df.stack()
s[s == 'Mangos'].index
```

---

```
MultiIndex([(1, 'column3')])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where` as well.

#### Code:

```py
import numpy as np
[(df.index[i], df.columns[c]) for i, c in zip(*np.where(df.isin(['Mangos'])))]
```

#### Output:

```py
[(1, 'column3')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a simple search yourself.

```
coordinates = []
indices = df.index
columns = df.columns
for index in indices: # df is the DataFrame
         for col in columns:
             if df[col][index] == 'Mangos':
                 coordinates.append((index, col))
coordinates
```

Output:

[(1, 'column3')]